# Evernote getNoteContent() Asynctask Error

Tags: java, android, sdk, evernote

I´m doing a proyect using the SDK of Evernote for Android. I´m trying to get the content from one of my notes(onItemClick) but everytime I use the method, the application crash with a Thread Exception. 
This is the part of the code where I use the method:

```
public void onFragmentInteraction(Note note) throws EDAMUserException, EDAMSystemException, EDAMNotFoundException, TException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    String noteGuid = note.getGuid();
    String Content = new GetNoteTask().execute(noteGuid).get();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewNoteActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Content);
    startActivity(intent);

}

public class GetNoteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private EvernoteSession mEvernoteSession;


public String noteContent(String guid) throws EDAMUserException, EDAMSystemException, TException, EDAMNotFoundException {
    final EvernoteNoteStoreClient noteStoreClient = mEvernoteSession.getEvernoteClientFactory().getNoteStoreClient();
        String noteText;
        noteText = noteStoreClient.getNoteContent(guid);
        return noteText;
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String guid = params[0];
    String noteContent = null;
    try {
        noteContent = noteContent(guid);
    } catch (EDAMUserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EDAMSystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EDAMNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return noteContent;
}
}
```

The first method is located in my MainActivity which extends a Fragment. The second one is my Task to get the content note. It breaks when I initialize the Evernote client in the asynctask.

```
 final EvernoteNoteStoreClient noteStoreClient = mEvernoteSession.getEvernoteClientFactory().getNoteStoreClient();
        String noteText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. I can´t call the EvernoteClient without the used mEvernoteSession which is declared in my Main Activity, so I tried to send the noteStoreClient but it was always empty because the method was private and not protected, so I didn't fill it when I was sending it.

Finally I created a Static class where I save my variables:

```
 public static class MyTaskParams{
        public String guid;
        public EvernoteNoteStoreClient noteStore;


    public MyTaskParams(String noteGuid, EvernoteNoteStoreClient noteStoreClient) {
        this.guid=noteGuid;
        this.noteStore=noteStoreClient;
    }
```

and I sended it later to the AsyncTask.

```
 MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(noteGuid,noteStoreClient);

        GetNoteTask GetNoteTask = new GetNoteTask();
```

So finally my Asynctask looks like:

```
public class GetNoteTask extends AsyncTask<MainActivity.MyTaskParams,Void , String> {

public String noteContent(EvernoteNoteStoreClient noteStoreClient, String guid) throws EDAMUserException, EDAMSystemException, TException, EDAMNotFoundException {
        String noteText;
        noteText = noteStoreClient.getNoteContent(guid);
        return noteText;
    }


protected String doInBackground(MainActivity.MyTaskParams... params) {

    String noteContent = null;
    String guid = params[0].guid;
    EvernoteNoteStoreClient noteStoreClient = params[0].noteStore;
    try {

        noteContent = noteContent(noteStoreClient, guid);
    } catch (EDAMUserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EDAMSystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EDAMNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return noteContent;
}
```